# OpenPyXl cell text wrapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have two problems regarding the same issue which is text wrapping in OpenPyXl

When I try to wrap cell's text by using `.alignment.wrap_text = True` I get

```
    q_cell.alignment.wrapText = True
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'alignment'
```

The thing is that the variable contains not a string but a cell object which in my object explorer shows as having `alignment.wrapText`

[image: Declaring and modifying the variable]

[image: Variable in object explorer]

What am I doing wrong and why is the `q_cell` (which definitely contains an object) throwing such an error where it looks like string?

Comment: Are *all* values in `ws` `Cell`s?

Comment: add your full code here. not images

Comment: ws is the activeworksheet of a Workbook. When I loop through its elements I get Cell objects as in the image from Object Explorer. I can access .value which is a property of a cell but I cannot access alignment which is also a property.

@Kalana 
I really should not share the whole code as it is not a private project.

Comment: I do not ask to add entire project in here.  I have asked more code section than this. Without it this question may be leads to primly opinion based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample program to set the cell alignment.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Test"
ws['A1'] = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna felis sollicitudin mauris. Integer in mauris eu nibh euismod gravida. Duis ac tellus et risus vulputate vehicula. Donec lobortis risus a elit. Etiam tempor. Ut ullamcorper, ligula eu tempor congue, eros est euismod turpis, id tincidunt sapien risus a quam. Maecenas fermentum consequat mi. Donec fermentum. Pellentesque malesuada nulla a mi. Duis sapien sem, aliquet nec, commodo eget, consequat quis, neque. Aliquam faucibus, elit ut dictum aliquet, felis nisl adipiscing sapien, sed malesuada diam lacus eget erat. Cras mollis scelerisque nunc. Nullam arcu. Aliquam consequat. Curabitur augue lorem, dapibus quis, laoreet et, pretium ac, nisi. Aenean magna nisl, mollis quis, molestie eu, feugiat in, orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst."""
c = ws['A1']
c.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='general', vertical='bottom', text_rotation=0, wrap_text=True, shrink_to_fit=False, indent=0)
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

**EDIT**

The reason why it didn't work is because

```py
>>> type(c.alignment)
<class 'openpyxl.styles.proxy.StyleProxy'>
```

It is a Style Proxy object and doesn't allow accessing the attributes. You can only assign a new Style. You can have a look at the source [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/proxy.html#StyleProxy)

Comment: Thank you! It does work and I should have figured this out as I edited Font in a very similar manner. The only remaining question is why I cannot access this property directly if it is listed within my object?

Comment: Update the post.